# Create a BigQuery Session in R using bigrquery

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I am using the bigrquery package with documentation found here: https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/

I am connecting to GCP and would like to use "sessions" as defined here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sessions-create

The purpose would be to use SQL/BQ TEMPORARY tables in R.  The documentation does not indicate if this is supported.  Is there a way to create a persistent BQ session from R?